# How to use pagination in collection fetched by sortBy and where operators?

Tags: sorting, filter, pagination, laravel-5.5

I need pagination for my collection in which I have to apply lots of filters. But I'm unable to achieve this. I'm new to laravel so please show me the right way. 
My controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $view = $request['view'] ? $request['view'] :'grid'; 
    $purpose =  $request['purpose'] ? $request['purpose'] : 'rent'; 
    $sort =  $request['sort'] ? $request['sort'] : 'asc'; 

    $properties = $properties->where('purpose' , $purpose);
    if($sort == 'asc');
        $properties = $properties->sortBy('price');
     else 
         $properties = $properties->sortByDesc('price');
    $properties = $properties->paginate(5);

    return view('frontend.properties.index', [ 'view'=>$view , 'properties' => $properties , 'request'=> $request->all()  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue and in order to solve that, I have created a trait called PaginateCollection:

```
/*
 * Paginate the Laravel Collection before and/or after filtering.
 *
 */
trait PaginateCollection
{
    /**
     * Paginate the collection.
     *
     * @param   \Illuminate\Support\Collection|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  $collection
     * @param   integer  $perPage
     * @param   integer  $currentPage
     * @return  \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
     */
    public function paginate($collection, $perPage = 10, $currentPage = 1)
    {
        $offSet = ($currentPage * $perPage) - $perPage;

        $otherParams = [
            'path'  => request()->url(),
            'query' => request()->query()
        ];

        return new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $collection->forPage(Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() , $perPage),
            $collection->count(),
            $perPage,
            Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(),
            $otherParams
        );
    }
}
```

Perhaps, this should help you out.